# Tres hilos con tiempo de retardo para su ejecución

Tags: java, hilos

Estoy intentando hacer un pequeño programa en el cual haya tres hilos con un tiempo de retardo asignado aleatoriamente para su ejecución.

Por ejemplo, en su ejecución podría aparecer "El hilo 3 terminó y tuvo que esperar 1560 ms" y así con cada uno de los tres.

Tengo este código pero no termino de darle forma:

```
public class HiloThread extends Thread {
    private int suma = 0;
    private long espera;

    public void run() {
        try {
            espera = (long) (Math.random() * 10000);
            sleep(espera);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(getName() + "terminó y tuvo que esperar" + espera + " ms");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sí perdona, tienes razón

Comment: Pero que necesitas?, solo hace falta que crees tus objetos y los ejecutes.